# My Flutter app is stuck in installing Apk while running it

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

My Flutter app works perfectly fine. But when I add the following dependency of firebase admob for Ads, it get stuck at installing apk file when I run it.

```
firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+1
```

When I remove it, it again works fine. I have restarted the app, cleared cache, done flutter run but none of the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Android Manifest xml file in android.  It should include the admob id for your app after "activity":